# rubymine 'what are you' feature

Tags: rubymine

Being a newbie to Rubymine, I am curious is there is way for me to have some kind of recorded session going that will show me what ruby code is executed when I click something in what I am testing?

I am not a 'developer', I am a tester, but in order to survive in the testing work, I need to learn how to use ruby (via rubymine) for automation.

I learn best by seeing how it is done and adapting to new scenarios.  And if I can see what 'ruby' i should use to click a button (or is it really a link?).

Thank you for your time

Comment: But if you're not a developer, why do you need to know what code executes? Does it matter? What matters is whether code produces expected behavior or not, right?

Comment: Having said that, what you want can be described as "tracing". Rubymine is a powerful IDE and maybe it even has this somewhere. Tracing is a double-edged sword, though. Depending on the size of the app, it can produce megabytes of source code references for just one tiny click. If you don't restrict tracing to your app code and allow gems/core as well, it can be tens of megabytes. How are you going to analyze that? :)

Comment: You can get some initial pointers from inspecting rails server log, It shows params, controller/action which handled your requests. You can then dig in from there, using rubymine's excellent navigation capabilities. This, however, implies that you run a rails server locally (something completely trivial for a developer, but perhaps not for a non-dev tester).

Comment: I need to know this because I have the write the ruby for the gherkins and understand how to 'adapt' it for other usage.  Thanks for the terminology of 'tracing' that will help in my search for a better answer.  I hope Rubymine has a 'trace' feature.  Also. I will ask co-workers to show me how to read the 'rails server log' to see if I can read that for some insight.  Hopefully you can see my struggles.  I just want to know what I need to write for a 'ruby' command on how to click that button (oh, wait the developer made that 'link' look like a button, so it is really not a a 'button').

Comment: I myself don't use cucumber (use capybara instead), but isn't it as easy as `click_button "Save"` or something? And then some code runs and you verify its __outputs__ (records created in the database, emails are sent, some info displayed on a page or whatever needs to be checked there). You don't need to know what code exactly just ran to do any of those things, I think.

Comment: Just to be clear on what I am hoping to find for a 'tool'.  I want a tool (even if it is not in Rubymine, that will give me the ruby 'commands' that were done to click the button.  The 'output' of what happens when the button is clicked is not important to me (for the moment).  Here is a current example of something that works on my current app.               When /^(?:|I )look for "([^"]*)" and "([^"]*)" it$/ do |center,button|
 page.find(:xpath,"//tr//td[@class ='t15data'][contains(.,\"#{center}\")]/../td[1]/a").click.
 step %{And I click the "#{button}" button}
end.

Comment: Basically, I want a tool to tell me how to click the 'button' if my 'inspect' element show me the following information.  //*[@id="R16521416950587350"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a

<a href="javascript:apex.navigation.redirect('f?p=112:47:2926343433173::NO:47::');">Create</a>